# How do I prevent the [div] from jumping out of the box when clicked on?

Tags: html

The **1st Code** uses `display:inline-block;vertical-align` the **2nd Code** uses `float:left;margin:` Also, the **1st Code** uses`</br>` tags which without them it would fall apart.

The **2nd Code** doesn't come apart when you zoom text in, the **1st Code** does.

**Code 1.)** When you click on the div here it stays in the box http://www.cssdesk.com/DQJFx

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfDnB.png

**Code 2.)** When you click on the div here it jumps out of the box. How do I prevent it from jumping out of the box using this code? Also, on this one, how would I move it 2px over to the right cause it's off by that much? http://www.cssdesk.com/GmM8L

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HZwm.png

```
<a href="" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0; color:#000000; border-top-left-radius:50px;"></a>

<a href="" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c; color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px;background-color:#edc951;color:#000000; border-top-right-radius:50px"></a>

<div style="width:266px" onclick="myObject=document.getElementById('myObj'); myObject.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
<a style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 88px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer; background-color:#ffffff; color:#000000; 
border-left:89px solid #00ffff;border-right: 89px solid #ff00ff;border-radius: 50px;"> </a>
</div>

<div id="myObj" style="display: none;">

</div>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0;color:#000000; clear:left;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#abe9f7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#00a0b0'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c;color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#badac5'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#6a4a3c'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f; color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#b7ab9d'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#cc333f'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#4679c7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#eb6841'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951; color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#45bf21'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#edc951'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0;color:#000000; clear:left;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c; color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841; color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0;color:#000000; clear:left;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0;color:#00a0b0; clear:left;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0; color:#000000; clear:left; border-bottom-left-radius:50px;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left;margin:2px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951;color:#000000; border-bottom-right-radius:50px;"></a>
```

Comment: Break your css out of your html; that inline stuff is a pain to mess with.

Comment: I'm only talking abut the first 5 blocks, and the ones below, isn't there something I could put in each of them that will work?

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271294/why-is-it-or-was-it-important-to-separate-css-from-html

Comment: And if " only talking abut the first 5 blocks" then remove the blocks from your sample that aren't needed.

Comment: Why can't I keep the rest of them? Than how was it done here keeping all the blocks? http://codepen.io/cpradio/pen/wWoPpQ

Comment: You can do what you want, but I (and others probably) don't want to help you figure out messy code.

Comment: But, the solution would be to put a small piece of code into each of the blocks that would make it work, but I can't figure what piece of code would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing this piece of code. [margin:0 0 0 2px; clear:left;]

Answer (score 1):

You should use different margins for your `<a>` elements.

For the first five, use this: `margin: 2px 2px 0 2px;`

For the 6th (inside the div): `margin: 0;`

For the next five: `margin: 0 2px 2px 2px;`

Margins (and paddings) applied clockwise in the following order: top right bottom left.

Comment: I can't see any difference. And also the code is the same.

Comment: These links work!!!! Here: When you click on the [div] here it stays in the box http://www.cssdesk.com/DQJFx When you click on the [div] here it jumps out of the box. How do I prevent it from jumping out of the box? Also, on this one, how would I move it 2px over to the right cause it's off by that much? http://www.cssdesk.com/GmM8L